# iTunes Connect: "Release this version" delay?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Once I click "Release this version" in iTunes Connect, how long does it take for the new version to be available in the App Store?

Comment: Not that long, it depends how quickly it can be replicated around Apple's servers.

Comment: Similar amount of time to DNS propogation?

Comment: I'm sure I've had an app appear within 10-15 mins but then I couldn't say how long that is for other users in different locations etc...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's publishing process and not about code.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Apple doesn't guarantee how much time it will take. Per "version [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf):

> Click the Release This Version button that appears.
>
> Your app version will then be live on the App Store **pending the customary processing times**.

After you clicked "release this version", your app will go live on Apple's many iTunes servers. I think the transfer processes to each server have different delay time. My experience is that this takes 15 minutes - 4 hours.

Comment: Update 10/2016: I received an email from Apple after clicking 'Release this Version'  That stated: *It can take up to 24 hours before your app is available on the App Store. This delay is dependent on any app availability issues.* <- whatever that means!

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, I only had to wait about 30 minutes for it to go live.  Not sure if this matters or not- but I was pushing an *update* to an app that had an already-live previous version.  It's possible that it would take longer for a new app if this is your first version.

Comment: The link to iTunes developer guide is broken. Please update to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html

Comment: What about how long does it take for the update to propagate to user's iPhones?

Comment: Update 10/2020: After click on "Release this Version" it took 30 minutes ~ 1hour to being available in stores.

Answer (score 21):

This time (at least in my experience) tends to range from anywhere between a couple minutes and 1-2 hours, but will definitely be updated within the day. I have noticed that apps appear to show up on iTunes faster than they show up in the App Store.